# Function not displaying return value - C++

Tags: c++

After a bit of tinkering, I finally came up with a function that determines the data type of any value (to a fixed extent).

But when I try to print out the return value from this function (`char*`), nothing gets printed out.

```
template <typename data> inline char* typeOf(data arg) {
    const std::type_info& type = typeid(arg);
    char* typeName;

    if (type == typeid(bool)) strcpy(typeName, "boolean");
    else if (
        type == typeid(double) ||
        type == typeid(float) ||
        type == typeid(int) ||
        type == typeid(long double) || type == typeid(long int) || type == typeid(long long) ||
        type == typeid(signed int) || type == typeid(signed long int) || type == typeid(signed short int) ||
        type == typeid(short int) ||
        type == typeid(unsigned int) || type == typeid(unsigned long int) || type == typeid(unsigned short int)
    ) strcpy(typeName, "number");
    else if (
        type == typeid(char) ||
        type == typeid(signed char) ||
        type == typeid(std::string) ||
        type == typeid(unsigned char) ||
        type == typeid(wchar_t)
    ) strcpy(typeName, "string");
    else if (type == typeid(void)) strcpy(typeName, "void");
    else strcpy(typeName, "null");

    // Expectation: Print out the value here
    // Problem: It does not print anything!
    std::cout << typeName << std::endl;

    return typeName;
}
```

I'm sure it's something I'm not familiar with but any help explaining why nothing gets printed from `std::cout` would be appreciated. The goal is to have a function determine the data type of a value and return a character string based off that.

Any improvements to this function would be appreciated as well.

Comment: What is this mysterious "string" object, referenced in the code, that seems to perform some unknown task? Oh, and this should be simpler, and cleaner, to do with elementary template specializations, and appropriate usage of `std::numeric_limits`. typeid-based finagling always looks ugly, and should only be used as a measure of absolutely the last resort. Here, I can't think of anything that cannot be done with bog standard specialization.

Comment: `char* typeName;` is an uninitialized variable, all those `strcpy` invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. Woops! I forgot to change that: the `string` object contains all my preferred string manipulation functions, such as `strcpy`.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I don't understand what you mean by 'undefined behavior'. Please add on to that.

Comment: It means that your program is ill-formed and that anything can happen, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub . And logically thinking, where do you think `strcpy` is going to copy the text to, when you haven't provided storage for it?

Comment: When you use strcpy the destination must be just allocated, you have declared a pointer that point to nothing so the copy don’t happen

Comment: "Undefined behavior" is a more technical term for a "bug". Go open your C++ book to the chapter that explains what `strcpy()` does, then ponder on the subject where exactly your `typeName` pointer is pointing to. Finally, all modern C++ compilers should be screaming bloody murder, here. Please do not ignore messages from your compiler. Even if the compiler still produces some code that technically executes, your compiler will always complain to you for a reason. A good reason.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. Yea, you're right, my compiler does complain with a few warnings. I'll adhere to good practice from now on then.

Although to be honest, I'd like to know how to at least get this function working before I attempt anything else (such as considering as warnings produced by my C++ compiler).

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips how to debug your code.

Comment: Also you should learn about `new` and `delete`. Better yet, use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `char* typeName` to `char* typeName=new char[50]` 50 is just a number for example, is a dimension that can contains all the string you have written in your code. Note that strcpy(char* destination, const char* source) require that destination point to a location which size is greater than source so the destination can contains all the source. I suggest you to use the string for typeName and not char*. Remember that the pointer to char* you return need a delete somewhere in your code.